# How to get the last part of $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I can't figure out how to get the last part of $(MSBuildProjectDirectory).

For example, if the value was "c:\development\projects\project_branch" then I want just the last part "project_branch".

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to use this value for?

Comment: Want to deploy binaries for branches to a location that organizes the folders by branch name. So the closest thing without referring to subversion seems to be the folder name where our msbuild file is. There is a deploy task we use for automated nightly build, so the objective is to add a deploy task for branch.

Answer (score 4):

In 4.0+ you can use Property Functions to do this in one line.

In this case for example
`$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))`

or you could use a String function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="BuildAll" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <Target Name="GetMSBuildProjectLocalDirectory">
        <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
            <Output ItemName="MSBuildProjectDirectoryMeta" TaskParameter="Include"/>
        </CreateItem>
        <CreateProperty Value="%(MSBuildProjectDirectoryMeta.Filename)">
            <Output PropertyName="LocalDirectory" TaskParameter="Value"/>
        </CreateProperty>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="GetMSBuildProjectLocalDirectory">
        <Message Text="$(LocalDirectory)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're following best practice, then your project directory will have the same name as your project file.  Therefore, you should be able to use:

```
$(MSBuildProjectName)
```